# How to get an implementation class instance from the proxy instance in Java

Tags: java, spring, interface, implementation, autowired

I have some weird problem while writing JUnit test that I'm able to Autowired one service implementation class but not able to Autowired another one. The applicationContext configuration of ServiceImpl1 and ServiceImpl2 are similar.

```
@Autowired 
private ServiceImpl1 serviceImpl1;   //This one works.

@Autowired 
private ServiceImpl2 serviceImpl2;   //This one doesn't work.
```

But this one will work

```
@Autowired 
private Service2 service2;   //This one works.
```

Here ServiceImpl2 is the implementation class of Service2. How can I get the instance of ServiceImpl2 from service2?

I would like to test some methods of ServiceImpl2 which are not in interface Service2.

Or if you know how I can make the Autowired work for class ServiceImpl2?

Comment: Is there a bean created/configured that you can autowire for that type?

Comment: Yes. ServiceImpl1 and ServiceImpl2 are configured in the same applicationContext.xml

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Is there any link between ServiceImpl2 and ServiceImpl1? Does ServiceImpl2 implement Service1 as well?

Comment: Yes. ServiceImpl2 is autowired as a property of ServiceImpl1.

Comment: The error I get is 

 No qualifying bean of type [xxx.service.ServiceImpl2] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: You could just use `new Service2Impl()`.

Comment: It won't work. It will miss the properties in ServiceImpl2.

Comment: You are using interfaces so you should already be programming to the interfaces and not the actual concrete implementations. Spring is probably creating a proxy (due to `@Transactional` or `@Cacheable` or `@Async` to name a few) as you are implementing interfaces that will be a JDK dynamic proxy, so a bean of type `Service2` (your interface) is available but not of the concrete type. So as mentioned you should be programming to interfaces already so inject into a field of `Service2` and `Service1` instead.

Comment: Also if you want to test some methods of that class then create a unit test and just create a new instance and mock/stub the needed properties. Don't use an integration test for that. Also if you need to test those methods in isolation there is probably something wrong with your abstraction / interface declaration as those methods should be tested as part of testing your public API.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer from another post.

> I find good for me solution on
>   http://www.techper.net/2009/06/05/how-to-acess-target-object-behind-a-spring-proxy/
>
> ```
> @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
> protected <T> T getTargetObject(Object proxy, Class<T> targetClass) throws Exception {
>   if (AopUtils.isJdkDynamicProxy(proxy)) {
>     return (T) ((Advised)proxy).getTargetSource().getTarget();
>   } else {
>     return (T) proxy; // expected to be cglib proxy then, which is simply a specialized class
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Usage
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onSetUp() throws Exception {
>   getTargetObject(fooBean, FooBeanImpl.class).setBarRepository(new MyStubBarRepository());
> }
> ```